# HibernateTemplate is null

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am making a web application on STS. I am using jars of Spring 3.1.0 and HIbernate 4.0.1. I am including jars in project build path. 
In DAO layer when I am trying to make a HibernateTemplate object , it is not getting instantiate, It is null there. I don't understand why it is null.

Earlier I was getting an error like NoClassDefinitionFound: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate....Then I included these jars in WEB-INF->lib folder and then this error was removed but still hibernateTemplate object is null. Can there be any issue regarding position of beans.xml in project folders. ? Can anyone help me.

Below is code for my beans.xml and Userinfo.java.

---

[b]Beans.xml[/b]

Only relevant part of bean.xml

```
<bean id="hibTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sfBean" />
</bean>
```

---

[b]UserinfoDao.java[/b]

```
package com.home.dao;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

import com.home.pojo.User;

public class UserinfoDao {

    public UserinfoDao() {

            super();

        }

    private static HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        UserinfoDao.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }

    public static void fetchUserInfo(){
        try{
            User user = (User)hibernateTemplate.get(User.class, 111);
        }catch(NullPointerException npe){
            npe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Hibernate 4 and you are using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate` from Hibernate 3 package.

This template is not supported anymore. You can do [declarative transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative).

Answer (score 0):

Your version makes me believe that you are simply accessing your bean with `static` method:

```
UserinfoDao.fetchUserInfo();
```

Looks like you are missing few key points of Spring. First of all you should not use `static` methods and fields, try with the following class:

```
public class UserinfoDao {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }

    public void fetchUserInfo(){
        try{
            User user = (User)hibernateTemplate.get(User.class, 111);
        }catch(NullPointerException npe){
            npe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Now you need to obtain an instance of Spring bean somehow. You cannot simply use `new UserinfoDao()` operator. You must either declare your bean in XML or via annotations (and declare dependency on `HibernateTemplate`.

Finally you shouldn't normally catch `NullPointerException`, but I understand this if for ddebugging purposes.